# Get UL to grow with contents (inline block list items)

Tags: css, menu, panel

I have a css menu I am working on but having trouble getting list items to float left without setting the width of the parent UL.

I've set up a JS fiddle so you can take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/FkK7Y/1/

If you take a look at the "products menu" you'll see I've got two sets of links (outlined in a pretty pink line) that are stacking one on top of the other. I would like these sets of links to float side by side each other (making he submenu more panelish). I feel like inline-block (see li class="subMenu") *should* work here, but doesn't.

```
.mainMenu ul.subMenu li.subMenu {
  border:1px solid pink;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
 }
```

However, if I set the width to the parent UL (also class="subMenu" -I have a width parameter that is commented out currently in the code, feel free to fiddle to see it in action) the inline-block appears to work on the list items.

```
.mainMenu ul.subMenu {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  top:34px;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0 0 10px 10px;
  z-index:-1;
  border:1px solid #600;
  min-width:100px;
  /*width:200px;*/ }
```

But as each sub-menu panel may have one or more of these menus I do not want to specify a width.. I'd like it to grow with the number of lists items I add to it.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need to add:

```
.subMenu{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/FkK7Y/2/

Comment: Thanks! It works great in chrome, but not in firefox or ie on my actual working copy (does JS fiddle though) .. could be something else in my code tripping it up for those two browsers. Will keep at it.

Comment: Let me know if you come across any more questions.